# Taking list of aircraft and making a spec sheet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of aircraft from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regional_airliners and I would like to get the specifications from each aircraft and paste them into a new sheet in excel so I can make an overarching comparision table. What would be the best way to go about this?

Edit for clarification:

I want to follow the links to the Specifications on a seperate page. For example the first entry is Airbus A220, I want to follow the link in that table to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A220#Specifications and extract the Specifications table so I can have details of each aircraft.

Comment: Are you OK to have current, historical, etc in different sheets (in tables)?

Comment: Yes thats fine, Ive added some clarification in a post below.

Comment: We add clarity by editing our original posts here on Superuser. We're not a forum, we're a QA site, which I'd a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

So excel doesnt have the functionality to follow links so I made a python script that does. It basiclly uses beautifulsoup to scrap the page for links and vist each one. It then uses pandas to convert the table found under Specifications on that page which is saved as a new sheet in excel.

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re

wikiurl="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regional_airliners"
table_class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"

# get main table and grab links from first column of table
response=requests.get(wikiurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = [items.find("a")["href"] for items in soup.find(class_="wikitable").find_all("tr")[1:] ]

# open excel file and and loop over each link extension
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test_out.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')
for link in links:
    testurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + link
    response=requests.get(testurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # remove refrences that wiki adds eg [0,1]
    for tag in soup.find_all(class_="reference"):
        tag.decompose()
    span = soup.find('span', {'id': re.compile("Specifications*")})

    # if there is a table found save to a new sheet in excel 
    # with the name of the link
    if span != None:
        table = span.parent.find_next_siblings("table")
        try:
            specs = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
            name = link.split('/')[-1][:31]
            specs.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
        except Exception as e:
            print("failed to add: " + link)
            print(e)
            print("___________________________")

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: **I am not sure that this will work satisfactorily** (1) Excel Document will contain **unwanted Data** in large text, not in cells & there will be lots of **missing Data** (2) In Post, you gave Example "Airbus A220" Specifications table. which implies tabular output. Check (2A) "CASA C-212 Aviocar" which has normal text with embedded table (2B) "Cessna 208" which has no table at all but has normal text (2C) "Dornier 228/Dornier 228NG " which has no table for 228, but only for NG variant (2D) "Xian Y-7 / MA60 / MA600" Single Item in Main table has 3 Pointers .... [ cont ]

Comment: .... [ cont ] (3) All have multiple tables outside of Specifications Section. (4) Currently this is a Python Script which **blindly** Parses the Main Wiki to get some content by following a Pointer to the other wiki without checking "meaningfulness" of the "Semi-Structured Data" (5) You will not be getting your "overarching comparision table" (6) A manual Process will give better output in 20-30 minutes.